# Determine transformation matrix of $f(v)=a\times v$ where $a\in V$ is a fixed vector and $f:V \to V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and $a\in V$ is a fixed vector. Let's define a function $f:V \to V$ with $f(v) = a \times v$. Check if $f$ is a linear operator. If it is, determine it's transformation matrix in respect to standard basis.

So, it is indeed a linear operator because:

$(\forall x, y \in V) \space \space  f(x+y)=a \times(x+y)=a\times x + a\times y = f(x) + f(y)$

$(\forall x \in V)(\forall \alpha \in F) \space \space f(\alpha x) = a \times (\alpha x) = \alpha (a\times x) = \alpha f(x)$

Now I need to find it's transformation matrix. Since we don't know the dimension of $V$ we have:

$a=
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1}\\
    a_{2}\\
    \vdots\\
    a_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
$ and $e_{1} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    0\\
    \vdots\\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
$. How do I find $a\times e_{1}$ and the transformation matrix?

Comment: What's $a\times v$? There is no vector multiplication on a generic vector space. And a generic vector space has no “standard basis”.

Comment: Well I got the problem written like this, I assumed it's a vector product since it doesn't say otherwise and $\times$ in vector spaces usually means vector product. That is what confuses me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector product can only be defined over three-dimensional spaces, so probably your space is $F^3$; if $\{\mathbf{e}_1,\mathbf{e}_2,\mathbf{e}_3\}$ is the standard basis, then the vector product $\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{v}$ is the “formal determinant”
$$
\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{v}=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & v_1 & \mathbf{e}_1\\
a_2 & v_2 & \mathbf{e}_2 \\
a_3 & v_3 & \mathbf{e}_3
\end{bmatrix}=
(a_2v_3-a_3v_2)\mathbf{e}_1-(a_1v_3-a_3v_1)\mathbf{e}_2+(a_1v_2-a_2v_1)\mathbf{e}_3
$$
to be expanded with Laplace’s rule with respect to the third column. Then
$$
\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{e}_1=a_3\mathbf{e}_2-a_2\mathbf{e}_3
\qquad
\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{e}_2=-a_3\mathbf{e}_1+a_1\mathbf{e}_3
\qquad
\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{e}_3=a_2\mathbf{e}_1-a_1\mathbf{e}_2
$$
so the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\
a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\
-a_2 & a_1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I guess that is the only logical solution, I don't know why it says only $F$.